# Cannot install Windows Powershell on Vista64

Tags: windows-vista, installation, powershell-2.0

I am desperately trying to install Powershell 2.0 on my Windows Vista 64 system. I downloaded KB968930 like a hundred times but when I start it it always says that I cannot use it with my system. Something like the update is not appropriate for this system (I have a German Vista...).
I googled and tried a lot, I don't have Powershell 1.0 installed or anything.
So I'm kind of out of options.
Any help?

EDIT: Vista SP2 is installed and I downloaded the correct KB file.

EDIT2: I just downloaded the KB file again and started it. Here is what the `WindowsUpdate.log` file says:

```
2013-05-30  20:41:22:419    2168    b00 Misc    ===========  Logging initialized (build: 7.6.7600.256, tz: +0200)  ===========
2013-05-30  20:41:22:419    2168    b00 Misc      = Process: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Security Client\MpCmdRun.exe
2013-05-30  20:41:22:419    2168    b00 Misc      = Module: C:\Windows\system32\wuapi.dll
2013-05-30  20:41:22:419    2168    b00 COMAPI  -------------
2013-05-30  20:41:22:419    2168    b00 COMAPI  -- START --  COMAPI: Search [ClientId = Microsoft Security Essentials (EDB4FA23-53B8-4AFA-8C5D-99752CCA7094)]
2013-05-30  20:41:22:424    2168    b00 COMAPI  ---------
2013-05-30  20:41:22:424     456    81c Agent   *************
2013-05-30  20:41:22:424    2168    b00 COMAPI  <<-- SUBMITTED -- COMAPI: Search [ClientId = Microsoft Security Essentials (EDB4FA23-53B8-4AFA-8C5D-99752CCA7094)]
2013-05-30  20:41:22:424     456    81c Agent   ** START **  Agent: Finding updates [CallerId = Microsoft Security Essentials (EDB4FA23-53B8-4AFA-8C5D-99752CCA7094)]
2013-05-30  20:41:22:424     456    81c Agent   *********
2013-05-30  20:41:22:424     456    81c Agent     * Online = Yes; Ignore download priority = No
2013-05-30  20:41:22:424     456    81c Agent     * Criteria = "(IsInstalled = 0 and IsHidden = 0 and CategoryIDs contains '6b9e8b26-8f50-44b9-94c6-7846084383ec' and CategoryIDs contains 'e0789628-ce08-4437-be74-2495b842f43b')"
2013-05-30  20:41:22:424     456    81c Agent     * ServiceID = {7971F918-A847-4430-9279-4A52D1EFE18D} Third party service
2013-05-30  20:41:22:424     456    81c Agent     * Search Scope = {Machine}
2013-05-30  20:41:22:429     456    81c Misc    Validating signature for C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution\WuRedir\9482F4B4-E343-43B6-B170-9A65BC822C77\muv4wuredir.cab:
2013-05-30  20:41:22:454     456    81c Misc     Microsoft signed: Yes
2013-05-30  20:41:32:138    2776    2c4 Misc    ===========  Logging initialized (build: 7.6.7600.256, tz: +0200)  ===========
2013-05-30  20:41:32:138    2776    2c4 Misc      = Process: C:\Windows\system32\wusa.exe
2013-05-30  20:41:32:138    2776    2c4 Misc      = Module: C:\Windows\system32\wuapi.dll
2013-05-30  20:41:32:137    2776    2c4 COMAPI  -----------  COMAPI: IUpdateServiceManager::AddScanPackageService  -----------
2013-05-30  20:41:32:138    2776    2c4 COMAPI    - ServiceName = Eigenständiges Windows-Updateinstallationsprogramm
2013-05-30  20:41:32:138    2776    2c4 COMAPI    - ScanFileLocation = C:\c06022b68c68bb9e25\wsusscan.cab
2013-05-30  20:41:32:144     456    e38 Misc    Validating signature for C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution\ScanFile\9fdf732b-c994-4ee9-bf5e-29db9b945212\Source.cab:
2013-05-30  20:41:32:154     456    e38 Misc     Microsoft signed: Yes
2013-05-30  20:41:32:181     456    e38 DtaStor Default service for AU is {7971F918-A847-4430-9279-4A52D1EFE18D}
2013-05-30  20:41:32:181    2776    2c4 COMAPI    - Added scan package service, ServiceID = {9FDF732B-C994-4EE9-BF5E-29DB9B945212} Third party service
2013-05-30  20:41:32:182    2776    2c4 COMAPI  -------------
2013-05-30  20:41:32:182    2776    2c4 COMAPI  -- START --  COMAPI: Search [ClientId = wusa]
2013-05-30  20:41:32:182    2776    2c4 COMAPI  ---------
2013-05-30  20:41:32:187    2776    2c4 COMAPI  <<-- SUBMITTED -- COMAPI: Search [ClientId = wusa]
2013-05-30  20:41:36:119     456    81c Misc    Validating signature for C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution\WuRedir\9482F4B4-E343-43B6-B170-9A65BC822C77\muv4wuredir.cab:
2013-05-30  20:41:36:124     456    81c Misc     Microsoft signed: Yes
2013-05-30  20:41:36:154     456    81c Agent   Checking for updated auth cab for service 7971f918-a847-4430-9279-4a52d1efe18d at http://ds.download.windowsupdate.com/v10/1/microsoftupdate/redir/muauth.cab
2013-05-30  20:41:36:154     456    81c Misc    Validating signature for C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution\AuthCabs\authcab.cab:
2013-05-30  20:41:36:159     456    81c Misc     Microsoft signed: Yes
2013-05-30  20:41:38:557     456    81c Misc    Validating signature for C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution\AuthCabs\authcab.cab:
2013-05-30  20:41:38:557     456    81c Misc     Microsoft signed: Yes
2013-05-30  20:41:39:117     456    81c Misc    Validating signature for C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution\WuRedir\7971F918-A847-4430-9279-4A52D1EFE18D\muredir.cab:
2013-05-30  20:41:39:127     456    81c Misc     Microsoft signed: Yes
2013-05-30  20:41:39:177     456    81c Misc    Validating signature for C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution\WuRedir\7971F918-A847-4430-9279-4A52D1EFE18D\muredir.cab:
2013-05-30  20:41:39:182     456    81c Misc     Microsoft signed: Yes
2013-05-30  20:41:39:182     456    81c PT  +++++++++++  PT: Starting category scan  +++++++++++
2013-05-30  20:41:39:202     456    81c PT    + ServiceId = {7971F918-A847-4430-9279-4A52D1EFE18D}, Server URL = https://update.microsoft.com/v6/ClientWebService/client.asmx
2013-05-30  20:41:43:885     456    81c Misc    Validating signature for C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution\WuRedir\7971F918-A847-4430-9279-4A52D1EFE18D\muredir.cab:
2013-05-30  20:41:43:890     456    81c Misc     Microsoft signed: Yes
2013-05-30  20:41:43:940     456    81c Misc    Validating signature for C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution\WuRedir\7971F918-A847-4430-9279-4A52D1EFE18D\muredir.cab:
2013-05-30  20:41:43:945     456    81c Misc     Microsoft signed: Yes
2013-05-30  20:41:43:950     456    81c PT  +++++++++++  PT: Synchronizing server updates  +++++++++++
2013-05-30  20:41:43:950     456    81c PT    + ServiceId = {7971F918-A847-4430-9279-4A52D1EFE18D}, Server URL = https://update.microsoft.com/v6/ClientWebService/client.asmx
2013-05-30  20:41:52:301     456    81c Misc    Validating signature for C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution\WuRedir\7971F918-A847-4430-9279-4A52D1EFE18D\muredir.cab:
2013-05-30  20:41:52:306     456    81c Misc     Microsoft signed: Yes
2013-05-30  20:41:52:357     456    81c Misc    Validating signature for C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution\WuRedir\7971F918-A847-4430-9279-4A52D1EFE18D\muredir.cab:
2013-05-30  20:41:52:373     456    81c Misc     Microsoft signed: Yes
2013-05-30  20:41:52:388     456    81c PT  +++++++++++  PT: Synchronizing extended update info  +++++++++++
2013-05-30  20:41:52:388     456    81c PT    + ServiceId = {7971F918-A847-4430-9279-4A52D1EFE18D}, Server URL = https://update.microsoft.com/v6/ClientWebService/client.asmx
2013-05-30  20:41:52:636     456    81c DtaStor WARNING: Attempted to add URL http://download.windowsupdate.com/msdownload/update/common/2013/05/8189724_fa6e756c037a3de0478e7dc88d88ddb09163d3b7.cab for file +m51bAN6PeBHjn3IjYjdsJFj07c= when file has not been previously added to the datastore
2013-05-30  20:41:52:636     456    81c DtaStor WARNING: Attempted to add URL http://download.windowsupdate.com/msdownload/update/common/2013/05/8190269_1220b48c7f345c9815d5a285198a5958a233914e.cab for file EiC0jH80XJgV1aKFGYpZWKIzkU4= when file has not been previously added to the datastore
2013-05-30  20:41:52:636     456    81c DtaStor WARNING: Attempted to add URL http://download.windowsupdate.com/msdownload/update/common/2013/05/8188301_be4a05c61bc56140e7c7e80c4539701930fe3299.cab for file vkoFxhvFYUDnx+gMRTlwGTD+Mpk= when file has not been previously added to the datastore
2013-05-30  20:41:52:750     456    bdc AU  Triggering Offline detection (non-interactive)
2013-05-30  20:41:52:750     456    bdc AU  #############
2013-05-30  20:41:52:750     456    bdc AU  ## START ##  AU: Search for updates
2013-05-30  20:41:52:750     456    bdc AU  #########
2013-05-30  20:41:52:750     456    bdc AU  <<## SUBMITTED ## AU: Search for updates [CallId = {D7E8BCF2-5763-46CD-B32D-E97E2E8B0056}]
2013-05-30  20:41:52:755     456    81c Agent   Update {D69FE539-A1C5-472F-A590-A04832009AE2}.201 is pruned out due to potential supersedence
2013-05-30  20:41:52:755     456    81c Agent   Update {97711250-8DE9-4251-906F-8FA804D4C710}.201 is pruned out due to potential supersedence
2013-05-30  20:41:52:755     456    81c Agent   Update {57464E63-51B7-4F5F-9E14-77E9783B0EAC}.201 is pruned out due to potential supersedence
2013-05-30  20:41:52:755     456    81c Agent   Update {18F36DD4-9652-44AB-8D4D-CABC1D14EED0}.201 is pruned out due to potential supersedence
2013-05-30  20:41:52:755     456    81c Agent     * Added update {C70E43AC-A41B-4668-85B0-5413F86013F1}.201 to search result
2013-05-30  20:41:52:760     456    81c Agent     * Found 1 updates and 4 categories in search; evaluated appl. rules of 248 out of 260 deployed entities
2013-05-30  20:41:53:821     456    81c Agent   *********
2013-05-30  20:41:53:821     456    81c Agent   **  END  **  Agent: Finding updates [CallerId = Microsoft Security Essentials (EDB4FA23-53B8-4AFA-8C5D-99752CCA7094)]
2013-05-30  20:41:53:821     456    81c Agent   *************
2013-05-30  20:41:53:821     456    81c Agent   *************
2013-05-30  20:41:53:821     456    81c Agent   ** START **  Agent: Finding updates [CallerId = wusa]
2013-05-30  20:41:53:821     456    81c Agent   *********
2013-05-30  20:41:53:821     456    81c Agent     * Online = Yes; Ignore download priority = No
2013-05-30  20:41:53:821     456    81c Agent     * Criteria = "IsInstalled=0"
2013-05-30  20:41:53:821     456    81c Agent     * ServiceID = {9FDF732B-C994-4EE9-BF5E-29DB9B945212} Third party service
2013-05-30  20:41:53:821     456    81c Agent     * Search Scope = {Machine}
2013-05-30  20:41:53:826    2168    fcc COMAPI  >>--  RESUMED  -- COMAPI: Search [ClientId = Microsoft Security Essentials (EDB4FA23-53B8-4AFA-8C5D-99752CCA7094)]
2013-05-30  20:41:53:841    2168    fcc COMAPI    - Updates found = 1
2013-05-30  20:41:53:841    2168    fcc COMAPI  ---------
2013-05-30  20:41:53:841    2168    fcc COMAPI  --  END  --  COMAPI: Search [ClientId = Microsoft Security Essentials (EDB4FA23-53B8-4AFA-8C5D-99752CCA7094)]
2013-05-30  20:41:53:841    2168    fcc COMAPI  -------------
2013-05-30  20:41:53:891    2168    d20 COMAPI  -------------
2013-05-30  20:41:53:891    2168    d20 COMAPI  -- START --  COMAPI: Download [ClientId = Microsoft Security Essentials (EDB4FA23-53B8-4AFA-8C5D-99752CCA7094)]
2013-05-30  20:41:53:891    2168    d20 COMAPI  ---------
2013-05-30  20:41:53:891    2168    d20 COMAPI    - Forced: No; Download priority: 2
2013-05-30  20:41:53:891    2168    d20 COMAPI    - Updates in request: 1
2013-05-30  20:41:53:891    2168    d20 COMAPI    - ServiceID = {7971F918-A847-4430-9279-4A52D1EFE18D} Third party service
2013-05-30  20:41:53:891    2168    d20 COMAPI  <<-- SUBMITTED -- COMAPI: Download [ClientId = Microsoft Security Essentials (EDB4FA23-53B8-4AFA-8C5D-99752CCA7094)]
2013-05-30  20:41:53:991     456    81c PT  +++++++++++  PT: Synchronizing server updates  +++++++++++
2013-05-30  20:41:53:991     456    81c PT    + Offline serviceId = {9FDF732B-C994-4EE9-BF5E-29DB9B945212}
2013-05-30  20:41:53:991     456    81c PT  WARNING: Cached cookie has expired or new PID is available
2013-05-30  20:41:56:067     456    81c PT  +++++++++++  PT: Synchronizing extended update info  +++++++++++
2013-05-30  20:41:56:067     456    81c PT    + Offline serviceId = {9FDF732B-C994-4EE9-BF5E-29DB9B945212}
2013-05-30  20:41:56:137     456    81c Agent     * Found 0 updates and 59 categories in search; evaluated appl. rules of 129 out of 292 deployed entities
2013-05-30  20:41:56:927     456    81c Agent   *********
2013-05-30  20:41:56:927     456    81c Agent   **  END  **  Agent: Finding updates [CallerId = wusa]
2013-05-30  20:41:56:927     456    81c Agent   *************
2013-05-30  20:41:56:927     456    81c Agent   *************
2013-05-30  20:41:56:927     456    81c Agent   ** START **  Agent: Finding updates [CallerId = AutomaticUpdates]
2013-05-30  20:41:56:927     456    81c Agent   *********
2013-05-30  20:41:56:927     456    81c Agent     * Online = No; Ignore download priority = No
2013-05-30  20:41:56:927     456    81c Agent     * Criteria = "IsInstalled=0 and DeploymentAction='Installation' or IsPresent=1 and DeploymentAction='Uninstallation' or IsInstalled=1 and DeploymentAction='Installation' and RebootRequired=1 or IsInstalled=0 and DeploymentAction='Uninstallation' and RebootRequired=1"
2013-05-30  20:41:56:927     456    81c Agent     * ServiceID = {7971F918-A847-4430-9279-4A52D1EFE18D} Third party service
2013-05-30  20:41:56:927     456    81c Agent     * Search Scope = {Machine}
2013-05-30  20:41:56:932    2776    f88 COMAPI  >>--  RESUMED  -- COMAPI: Search [ClientId = wusa]
2013-05-30  20:41:56:932    2776    f88 COMAPI    - Updates found = 0
2013-05-30  20:41:56:932    2776    f88 COMAPI  ---------
2013-05-30  20:41:56:932    2776    f88 COMAPI  --  END  --  COMAPI: Search [ClientId = wusa]
2013-05-30  20:41:56:932    2776    f88 COMAPI  -------------
2013-05-30  20:42:07:499    2776    2c4 COMAPI  -----------  COMAPI: IUpdateServiceManager::RemoveService  -----------
2013-05-30  20:42:07:499    2776    2c4 COMAPI    - ServiceId = {9fdf732b-c994-4ee9-bf5e-29db9b945212}
2013-05-30  20:42:08:330    2776    2c4 COMAPI  IUpdateService removing volatile scan package service, serviceID = {9FDF732B-C994-4EE9-BF5E-29DB9B945212}
2013-05-30  20:42:08:332     456    e38 Agent   WARNING: WU client fails CClientCallRecorder::RemoveService with error 0x80248014
2013-05-30  20:42:08:332    2776    2c4 COMAPI  WARNING: ISusInternal::RemoveService failed, hr=80248014
```

Comment: @SimonLinder - Make sure you have `Windows Vista Service Pack 2` installed. After you do that make sure you use this installer http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=0f73efa2-f8d6-45f3-a8f8-5cdc205b119a

Comment: @Ramhound - As I said, I googled a lot and also made sure about all that...

Comment: The full log file would be helpful

Comment: upload the WindowsUpdate.log

Comment: See EDIT2. And thank you guys for your efforts.

Comment: the log doesn't show anything useful. Run eventlog, filter for the Powershell entries in"Setup" and export the entries. Also upload this data.

Comment: I couldn't find there any problem.

Comment: ok run **Windows6.0-KB968930-x64.msu /log:KB968930.log** and upload the log and dpx file. And please use the @ before my name so that I get notified about your reply.

Comment: is it fixed now?

Comment: @magicandre1981 Sorry, I gave up... My goal was to install MS SQL Management Studio which needs PowerShell. Finally I just installed version 1.0. So everything is fine for me now.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try this [FixIt utility](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/971058) to reset Windows Update components
2. Try the [Fix WU utility](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/repair-fix-windows-updates-with-fix-wu-utility)

   [image: 1]

Comment: Tried both, didn't help.