# I have updates to install but I can't see them in the "select the updates to install list"

Tags: windows-7, windows-update

I'm getting an empty list of updates when Windows Update says I have 8 important and 1 optional of them to install. I can't see their descriptions.

[image]

Any Idea?

Comment: [This answer](http://superuser.com/a/601906/138343) might help you as well.

Comment: Sorry I don't like magic tricks, I want a solution I can repeat because I know what the problem is

Answer (score 2):

Run Fixit 50202:

http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9665683

Here is a video which shows how to use it:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lZ_x6RM5zGk

Comment: Must restart explorer after run fix.

Comment: @Xilmiki: Thx! I could restart only expolrer.exe instead of computer. Nice! :)

Answer (score 1):

Actually it appears that the problem starts after extended period of PC being turned on, and/or being put to sleep and back. Try simply to kill explorer.exe and open it again.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever the bug is, it seems to fix itself* when you restart Windows explorer. You can accomplish that by two means:

- From task manager, kill all "explorer.exe" processes (when you're done, don't forget to File→Run a new `explorer`).
- Or just restart the computer.

I've tried some Microsoft fix-it tools but they don't do anything until I restart (and I'm sure it's the restart what fixes it anyway).

<sub>(*) Until it decides to happen again some weeks later.</sub>